# XCode 4 Won't Let Me Connect UITableView to its data source

Tags: ios, xcode4, xcode4.2

For some reason, I am unable with XCode 4 to connect a UITableView to the File's Owner in the XIB file. This connection is something I have done countless of times.

The File's Owner is a class which derives from UITableViewController.

I even tried the following
1) Used Interface Builder from XCode 3 (still have it installed) and there I am able to connect it no problem

2) In a different project, with XCode 4 I put a UITableView in a view and was able to connect it to the File's Owner even though that didn't derive from UITableViewController or implemented the data source protocol

This problem is happening to a couple XIB files in this project. Note this project and those XIBs were created using XCode 3.

Is that a bug or I am missing something?

Comment: Why don't you set its dataSource in code?

Comment: Thanks. I know I can but I have always done it in the XIBs and now I am wondering if something is broken or not.

Comment: Probably not, its probably just one minor setting that you are doing wrong. Ill post my suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of connecting your UITableView to your DataSource in Interface Builder, just connect it like so:

```
[myTableView setDataSource:self];
```

Comment: iBrad, thanks but that's not the answer I am looking for. I already knew how to do that. I am trying to find that "setting" that's causing the issue. Thx though.

Comment: If you control click your tableview and drag to your File's Owner row does the dataSource option pop up?

Comment: iBrad, thanks for keeping with me. I just tried again and lo and behold, it just worked. I did exactly the same way as I did before. I call an XCode bug.

Comment: Great! Accept my answer if it helped you out!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out restarting XCode was the solution. Well perhaps restarting my system too since I did both.